Heroku: 'slug size too large'
When I attempt to deploy my python (flask) application to heroku, I get the error that the slug size is too large. I'm not sure what would be taking up this much space. Then I run the command below.
$ du -ha --max-depth 1 /app | sort -hr
286M    /app
266M    /app/.heroku
14M     /app/.apt
6.9M    /app/lang
24K     /app/.profile.d
8.0K    /app/requirements.txt
4.0K    /app/runtime.txt
4.0K    /app/requirements.in
4.0K    /app/README.md
4.0K    /app/Procfile
4.0K    /app/Aptfile

Is there any way to reduce the size of /app/.heroku. I've been told this holds the python binaries? How can I reduce?
EDIT:
Dependancies listed below:
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
certifi==2022.12.7
Flask==3.0.3
Flask_Cors==4.0.0
flask_mailman==1.1.0
flask_session==0.8.0
google_api_python_client==2.122.0
numpy==1.26.4
openai==1.30.1
protobuf==5.26.1
pymongo==4.6.2
python_bcrypt==0.3.2
qdrant_client==1.9.1
Requests==2.32.2
sentence_transformers==2.4.0
spacy==3.7.4
stripe==8.7.0



What are your dependencies? Pretty sure you've got some big ones.

@Chris yeah that was the first thing I looked at. Edited the q to reflect them.
